# What's the design solution for this situation?

Tags: python, software-design

I have the following situation ( all 3 are functions in a python class ) where I have to send a message to a remote device with 2 callbacks that give detail about the state of the remote device.

```
# callback when a app has completed downloaded on a remote device
def handleAppDownloadComplete():
      #something

# callback when an app has restarted on a remote device
def handleAppRestart():
     # app restart callback


def sendMessage(message):

     // Do things like validation etc 
     sendMessageToRemoteDevice(message)
```

My situation is

1) call sendMessage when handleAppDownloadComplete callback is called

2) At any point during sendMessage(), if handleAppRestart() is called, stop execution of sendMessage(),  wait for handleAppDownloadComplete() to be called back and call sendMessage() again.

I have tried to use threading.events(), but this seems very cyclical for me. And to add, both the call backs are provided by third party libraries and I can't change them. Any better way/design to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#future (look at the example)

You could model the call to sendMessage() as a task which could be cancelled by handleAppRestart(). So you'd have a class variable task which would bind to a task.

```
import asyncio
class foo:
   task = None
   loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
def handleAppDownloadComplete()
{
   task = asyncio.ensure_future(sendMessage(bar))
   loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
}

# callback when an app has restarted on a remote device
def handleAppRestart()
{
    task.cancel()
}
@asyncio.coroutine
def sendMessage(message)
{
     // Do things like validation etc 
     sendMessageToRemoteDevice(message)
}
```

Btw what you gave in your question isn't Python code, and neither is my answer (Python doesn't use {} and I didn't indent correctly).

Anyway, answer is: Use asynchronous abstractions to do what you want.

EDIT: Wait, you can't change handleAppDownloadComplete(), handleAppRestart() or sendMessage(message)?

Comment: You are right. Changed the syntax. It is actually python code. Perils of coding in 2 different languages at the same time. I can find a way to add/edit the callbacks, but can't change when it is called. sendMessage(message) can be completely changed.

Comment: Btw. Asyncio is only for python 3.3